# Cannot POST Cosmos DB Stored Procedures using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to deploy stored procedures to a collection within an Azure Cosmos DB account as part of my deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps. Due to security reasons, I have to use the REST API (cannot use or import PowerShell modules to do this).

The build agents that I'm using are on-premise agents. Again, security reasons.

In order to generate an authorization token to make requests, I have the following PowerShell function:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Generate Authorization Key for REST calls
Function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$verb,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceLink,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$resourceType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$dateTime,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$keyType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$tokenVersion
    )

    $hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)

    $payLoad = "$($verb.ToLowerInvariant())`n$($resourceType.ToLowerInvariant())`n$resourceLink`n$($dateTime.ToLowerInvariant())`n`n"
    $hashPayLoad = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payLoad))
    $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayLoad);

    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$signature")
}
```

I then call this function within the POST function that I'm using to POST the stored procedure to Azure Cosmos DB:

```
Function Post-StoredProcToCosmosDb
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$EndPoint,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$DataBaseId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$CollectionId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$MasterKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$JSON
    )

    $Verb = 'Post'
    $ResourceType = "sprocs"
    $ResourceLink = "dbs/$DataBaseId/colls/$CollectionId"

    $dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
    $authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
    $header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime;"xs-ms-session-token"="28"}
    $contentType = "application/json"
    $queryUri = "$EndPoint$ResourceLink/sprocs"

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $queryUri  -Body $JSON

    return $result.statuscode
}
```

I see from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-stored-procedure) that I need to pass my stored procedure in the body as a string, so I set the path of my stored procedure to a variable like so:

```
$HelloWorld = Get-Content -Path '.\Databases\MyCosmosDB\MyCosmosCollection\Stored Procedures\HelloWorld.js' | Out-String
```

I then call my POST function like so:

```
Post-StoredProcToCosmosDb -EndPoint $env:COSMOSENDPOINT -DataBaseId $env:MYCOSMOSDB -CollectionId $MyCollection -MasterKey $env:MASTERKEY -JSON $HelloWorld
```

However, when I run the task, I get the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request 
>   At D:_workAzure\r12\a_Cosmos\Deployment\scripts\postStoredProcedures.ps1:61 char:15
>   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Method $Verb -Content ...
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

I have followed the example request body as outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-stored-procedure#request) for my stored procedure.

Here is what it looks like for your info:

```
"function () {\r\n    var context = getContext();\r\n    var response = context.getResponse();\r\n\r\n    response.setBody(\"Hello, World\");\r\n}"
```

I'm fairly new to PowerShell, so I'm wondering where I am going wrong. I've tried setting the `contentType` to both `application/json` and `application/query+json` but otherwise, I'm not sure where I am going wrong?

If anyone can provide any guidance on this, I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turns out the request body was wrong. It should be like this:

```
{
    "body":"function HelloWorld() {\r\n    var context = getContext();\r\n    var response = context.getResponse();\r\nresponse.setBody(\"Hello, World\");\r\n}",
    "id": "HelloWorld"
}
```

That's the acceptable request body for Stored Procedures. So what I should have done is set my $HelloWorld variable to:

```
$HelloWorld = Get-Content -Path '.\Databases\MyCosmosDB\MyCosmosCollection\Stored Procedures\HelloWorld.json' | Out-String
```

Hope my stupidity helps someone someday :/